# Passing parameter as keyword to new function

Tags: python

Say I have the following code:

```
def my_func(a, b, param="foo"):
    if param == "foo":
        obj = other_func(foo=(a, b))
    elif param == "bar":
        obj = other_func(bar=(a, b))
    elif param == "test":
        obj = other_func(test=(a, b))
```

Is there a more pythonic way to convert the argument into a keyword for a new function? This method gets tedious after a few if statements. Something like this would be better (just example):

```
def my_func(a, b, param="foo"):
    obj = other_func(param=(a, b))
```

After plenty of testing, the best I have found is the following:

```
def my_func(a, b, param="foo"):
    temp_str = f"{param}=(a, b)"
    obj = eval("other_func("+temp_str+")")
```

But I have only heard bad things about eval(), which I don't fully understand.

Comment: `eval()` is dangerous if you're evaluating input from user, but there's no problem if you generated yourself the string to be evaluated.

Comment: Ah yes I remember now, certain string inputs having far too much power, thanks. Good to know it's harmless as long as I make the strings!

Comment: Even if it's _safe_, there are still disadvantages to using eval.

Comment: What might those disadvantages be? By the way, your answer to unpack the dictionary works flawlessly and I much prefer it to eval().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `**` operator to unpack a dict and pass its items as keyword arguments to a function:

```
def my_func(a, b, param="foo"):
    obj = other_func(**{param: (a,b)})
```

Comment: Yep, I've definitely done exactly this, especially with Django. It's not the prettiest thing, but it's way safer than `eval`.